# Why is the scope of a Maven dependency ignored when launching Tomcat from Eclipse's plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, maven

I'm developing a Java webapp with Eclipse and Tomcat and Maven plugins.

I have a HTTPServlet in my project and my problem is the following : if I use Maven to deal with the javax.servlet package dependency, compilation is fine but when I launch Tomcat via the Tomcat Eclipse plugin, a jar is loaded with Tomcat even though its scope is set to "provided" in my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Thus, when I try to access my servlet on a browser, I get a java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.HelloServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet.

The solution i found for my development is to provide Tomcat libraries for compilation and remove the javax.servlet dependency from my pom.xml, but then, of course, compilation fails when I use the Maven command line tools.

Any idea why the Tomcat/Maven plugins are ignoring the "provided" scope of my pom.xml dependency ?

Comment: Are you manually adding the Tomcat dependencies to your project? If you've correctly set it up as a dynamic web project using WTP that should be done automatically. Can you clarify how you've set up your project? (E.g. project type in the create new project dialogue)

Comment: I created the project as a Maven project, not a dynamic web project.

Comment: I seem to recall that if you have the m2eclipse WTP integration installed, the m2eclipse plugin will recognise maven projects with WAR packaging as being WTP projects and will create them with the necessary WTP support in eclipse. Do you know if the m2eclipse WTP integration is installed?

Comment: didn't change much... not familiar with the WTP thing though...

Comment: WTP is eclipse Web Tools Platform. When correctly set up, it helps you develop servlets and other dynamic web projects, providing the necessary dependencies, such as the servlet api, and allowing you to control server instances, such as Tomcat or Glassfish, from within Eclipse for development & debugging. If the servlet dependencies are missing from Eclipse and you have to add them manually, it suggests to me a problem with the project setup in eclipse, rather than a specific Maven issue. Perhaps you could try recreating the project now the WTP integration is installed?